# Turtle Graphics - how can background image in the center after setting the world cooridinates?

Tags: python, image, coordinates, gif, turtle-graphics

I have been typically setting the world coordinates to the bottom left hand corner when using turtle graphics.

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Pen()
turtle.setup(500,500)
turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0,500, 500)
```

The challenges is that when I insert a background image

```
turtle.bgpic("cat.gif")
```

[image]

It is also being moved the original origin (0,0) which is now in the bottom left hand corner of the screen.  I need to move the center of the image to the center of my window.  Is there to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to poke about a bit "beneath the shell", you can manipulate this at the tkinter level:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 500, 500)

screen.bgpic("cat.gif")
canvas = screen.getcanvas()
canvas.itemconfig(screen._bgpic, anchor="sw")  # pylint: disable=W0212

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.dot(100)  # draw a large dot at (0, 0)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked as advertised, except that the picture is twelve pixels out of the corner.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this what you are hinting at with the pylint comment?